# Rails routes - override http verbs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to use `resources` to generate the following five routes:

```
      Prefix Verb URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
       lists GET  /lists(.:format)                lists#index
 create_list GET  /lists/create(.:format)         lists#create
        list GET  /lists/:id(.:format)            lists#show
destroy_list GET  /lists/:id/destroy(.:format)    lists#destroy
 update_list GET  /lists/:id/update(.:format)     lists#update
```

Note that all requests need to be GET requests. Instead of using patch, post, and delete, I am simply appending the action type to the URL. I need this to be able to use websockets (websockets can only do GET requests).

Here is what I have tried:

```
resources :lists, only: [:index, :show] do
  collection do
    get :create # should route to /lists/create, but routes to /lists
  end

  member do
    get :update # should route to /lists/:id/update, but routes to /lists/:id
    get :destroy # should route to /lists/:id/destroy, but routes to /lists/:id
  end
end
```

This results in the following:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern          Controller#Action
lists  GET  /lists(.:format)     lists#create
 list  GET  /lists/:id(.:format) lists#update
       GET  /lists/:id(.:format) lists#destroy
       GET  /lists(.:format)     lists#index
       GET  /lists/:id(.:format) lists#show
```

The problem here is that it seems to reject the keywords `:create`, `:update`, and `:destroy`, probably because it knows I am trying to do something unconventional.

I am aware that I could just write `get` five times with different routes, but I want to use `resources` so that I can nest routes, etc.

How can I get the five routes from the top of this question using `resource`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the obvious answer is to use strings instead of symbols.

```
resources :lists, only: [:index, :show] do
  collection do
    get 'create', as: 'create'
  end

  member do
    get 'update', as: 'update' 
    get 'destroy', as: 'destroy' 
  end
end
```

But I have a different question in return. What is the problem/feature/weird road/etc that makes you neglect the REST in this case?

Comment: That's great! I had no idea strings would be treated differently. Symbols work as long as they're not one of `:create`, `:update`, or `:destroy`, but I didn't think of trying strings.

I can't use RESTful routes because I need these routes to be accessible by websockets, and websockets can only do GET requests. That's why I need to override some paths, since otherwise they would collide.

Comment: The second part of the question would be, how can I get the prefix right? For example, `get 'create', as: :create` will result in a prefix of `create_lists`, but it should really be `create_list`. Same for the member routes...

Comment: the `create` route is the only one that's gonna be out of convention here if you again use strings inste ad of symbols, but I do think that it's a very minor inconvinience since you are violating the convention from the top)